# Changing a digit to a integer within string comprehension

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
multDigits :: String -> Int
multDigits "" = 1
multDigits str = [product x | x <- str, isDigit x, digitToInt x]
```

I basically need to get all of the digits from a string and find their product, but can't find much information online on how to use isDigit.

"Hello, m7 name is 9m1" should give the output 63. I am not allowed to use any other functions bar digitToInt.

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isDigit

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How is that link helpful at all? That function is already in the question.

Comment: seems fair to me as a response to "[I] can't find much information online on how to use isDigit."

Comment: I meant within string comprehension, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

`digitToInt x` will not work, since that is a *filter* in the list comprehension, and this thus means that `digitToInt x` should return a `Bool`. Even if somehow that would work, it would not *do* much, since it would convert it to an `Int`, and then you ignore the result.

You should put the `digitToInt` in the "*yield*" part of the list comprehension, so:

```
[digitToInt x | x <- str, isDigit x]
```

now we have a list of `Int`s, but this will not calculate the `product`, you can not put the [**`product :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:product) function in the yield part, since then you calculate the product per item, but you can not calculate the `product` of a simple `Int`. You thus calculate the product over the entire list, so:

```
multDigits :: String -> Int
multDigits str = product [digitToInt x | x <- str, isDigit x]
```

You can also make use of [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) and [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter), instead of using list comprehension, so:

```
multDigits :: String -> Int
multDigits = product . map digitToInt . filter isDigit
```

Comment: That you very much, you gave me a lot of useful key words to look up, and a very good explanation!